# Not able to make relationship correctly the rails way or a polymorphic relation ship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.3

I am using rails 5 and Ruby 2.3
I have a model name User created using the devise which can create jobs so the migration used for this is:

```
rails g model job user:references cader_id:integer
```

These jobs can be completed by the other user's with role Cader. When a Cader completed a job In it I store the user_id of that user in the job table as cader_id which is integer

What should be the correct way of doing it in the rails with proper indexing. So In case I want to search  all jobs completed by the user they get searched fast the indexing.

I can search all jobs created by that user like

```
user.jobs
```

similarly to search the user of a particular job that can be searched using

```
job.user
```

How can, I search all jobs completed by the user as user as Cader
like

```
cader.completed_jobs or user.completed_job
```

and to search for the particular Cader who completed the job like

```
job.cader
```

Thank in advance

for now to search Cader that completed a Particular job I have written the class method like

```
 def cader?
    cader = User.find(self.cader_id)
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a instance method `completed_jobs` in user model and fetch the completed_jobs by that user like this.

```
def completed_jobs
  Job.where(cader_id: id)
end
```

And to search for the particular `cader` change you're class method to job `instance method` as you're querying for a particular job instance.

Add index on `cader_id` to improve the search results

Comment: yes, that can be done by making the instance method in the user class, But when the jobs number in millions the it will search 1 million records one by one to get all the jobs done by that particular Cader which is very time consuming, I want to do it by using indexing

Comment: that is why i mentioned to add index on `cader_id` in Job class.